# Find count of an list2.item in list1

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list1 with these items:

```
"Test1"
"TestB"
"TestA"
```

and I have list2 with these items:

```
"Test1"
"Test2"
"Test3"
"Test4"
"Test5"
```

Case: `list2.Test1` is the only item from `list2` which occurs in `list1`, thats a positive case.

if `list1` has ONE item of `list2` then...

How can I express that with LINQ?

Comment: `list2.Intersect(list1)` - For getting elements which occurs in both collections.

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev You mean the distinct result list could have exactly 1 same item then my case is positive?

Comment: `Intersect` will return you `IEnumerable`. Then you can use any extension method  like `Any()`, `Distinct()`, `Count()` and so on...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var count = list2.Count(x => list1.Contains(x));
```

or

```
var count = list2.Intersect(list1).Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Use [Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx):

```
var count = list2.Except(list1).Count();
```

or

```
var count = list2.Intersect(list1).Count();
```

or

```
var count = list2.Count(x => list1.Contains(x));
```